# Can you tell me why the same command doesn't work on my Shell script on the "Quick Command" or "Auto Action" application?

Tags: macos, terminal

Photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umGZb.png

I don't know why it works in my terminal.

I have tried to find similar problems through search engines, but unfortunately none of them were solved.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems not too difficult, mainly the terminal environment, the solution is as follows:
Just change the path.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).